# Disable clickable links for misspelled words (flyspell)

Tags: flyspell

Is there a way to disable the way flyspell converts misspelled words into clickable links, as well as the background colour (pink, at least for my colour theme) it uses?

I find it confusing and unnecessary.

See here:

[image]

Comment: How about trying `(setq flyspell-mouse-map nil)`.  I have not tried it, but am trying to think of a way that does not involve modifying the placement of overlays in some of the internal functions of `flyspell-mode`.  If that doesn't work, you may wish to consider modifying `make-flyspell-overlay` to remove the placement of faces (`mouse-face`) and keymaps (`keymap`) -- e.g., comment out:  `(overlay-put overlay 'mouse-face mouse-face)` and `(overlay-put overlay 'keymap flyspell-mouse-map)`  I have not tried that either.

Comment: I tried with `(setq flyspell-mouse-map nil)`, but it the misspelled words are still clickable links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following code installs an advice, which removes the overlay properties which flyspell uses on incorrect words for mouse operations.

```
(defun make-flyspell-overlay-return-mouse-stuff (overlay)
  (overlay-put overlay 'help-echo nil)
  (overlay-put overlay 'keymap nil)
  (overlay-put overlay 'mouse-face nil))
(advice-add 'make-flyspell-overlay :filter-return #'make-flyspell-overlay-return-mouse-stuff)
```

---

To make above code working automatic from your init.el, it needs to be evaled after flyspell has been loaded. Below are two variants, one for users of `use-package` and one for users without `use-package`. Replace `...` with the above given code.

without `use-package`:

```
(with-eval-after-load "flyspell"
  ...
  )
```

with `use-package`:

```
(use-package flyspell
  :config
  ...
  )
```

Comment: As I see now, this is something similar to that what lawlist proposed as solution in a comment.

Comment: This works. Buy I have to manually run the code everytime I start Emacs. I placed it in my .emacs config, but I still have to run it again. Do you know why?

Comment: @NVaughan yes, it needs to be run after flyspell has been loaded. I will update my answer.

Comment: Thanks. I'm using the latter option, but it doesn't work...

Comment: My relevant config is here: https://gitlab.com/nivaca/dotemacs/-/raw/master/mylisp/myflyspell.el

Comment: Thanks, it's working now.

Comment: @NVaughan yeah I checked with your config fragment, it is also working here.